# What is the difference between 'Share Now' and 'Share to Feed'?

Tags: facebook

I can see a nice Facebook post that I would like to share with my own Friends. There are two similar options to do this. What is the difference between 'Share Now' and 'Share to Feed'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Share Now**

The post will be shared to your Feed and timeline with your current privacy settings.

**Share to Feed**

You can customize the post (example: add a description) *before* you share it. If the post includes a link, you can choose to share the link by itself, or click next to Include Original Post to keep the text from the original Feed post. You can click the audience selector to change your audience, then click Post.

Information as per [*Facebook help*](https://www.facebook.com/help/163779957017799)